# What's wrong with this proof (basic number theory)?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I tried to prove $$(\exists x \in \mathbb{Z}). ((\exists y \in \mathbb{Z}. x =3y + 1) \wedge (\forall y \in \mathbb{Z}. x^2 \neq 3y - 1))$$

I let $x = -2$. We know that $3(-1) + 1 = -2$, so there exists some $y \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $x = 3y+1$
($y = -1$).

Then, I assume that $x^2 = 3y - 1$. With $x = -2$, it's just algebra to show that $y = \frac{5}{3}$. This $y$ isn't an integer, and since it's the only solution to the equation, we see that for all $y \in \mathbb{Z}$, $x^2 \neq 3y-1$.

However, my TA said that this is incorrect, and her explanation was that $y$ is a sort of "local variable" in this problem. Can anyone explain what that means, and why my proof is wrong?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: Why not write it more clearly: $\,x\equiv 1,\ x^2\not\equiv -1\pmod{3}\ $ is solvable. Is that what you intended?

Comment: Your proof is correct. The only possible objection I see (which is different from what your TA says) might be that your detour via rational numbres might be frowned upon - but that should happen only at a very introductory level

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is correct. There are two $y$ variables defined in two different scopes: namely one quantified by $\exists$ and one quantified by $\forall$. It would have been erroneous to treat them as the same variable, which I think is what your TA was saying you did. But your proof doesn't do that so I think your TA was confused about your proof.